# Reduce line spacing in nomenclature

Tags: line-spacing, nomenclature

I am creating a nomenclature and would like to reduce line spacing. If I use the approach found online inserting the `\setlength{\nomitemstep}{-parsep}` command, all line skips are removed including the ones before and after the sub-section headings of the nomenclature. 
Is there a way of reducing the line space only for the individual items, however not for the headers?

Attached is an example code and a snapshot of the output:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, preprint]{elsarticle} 

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textbf{Other Variables}]}{}}} 
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
This is my text document.
\nomenclature[a]{$\sigma$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$\alpha$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$\beta$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$A$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$B$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$C$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$D$}{Variable explanation}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Christian
[image]

Comment: I think, the spacings is actually controlled in the `nomencl.ist` file

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the reply. As I am fairly new to LaTeX, could you let me know how I can access and edit that file in a way that solves my question above?

Comment: I'll try to do later on

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi Christian, I would appreciate if you could give me a hint on how to edit the .ist file to achieve the desired effect. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small bypass solution: Restore the `\noitemsep` value temporarily in a `\nomgroup` and use the newer value afterwards.

```
\documentclass[authoryear, preprint]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xpatch}



\newlength{\nomitemorigsep}
\setlength{\nomitemorigsep}{\nomitemsep}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}


\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
  \itemsep\nomitemorigsep%
  \ifthenelse{%
    \equal{#1}{A}%
  }{%
  \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]%

  }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Other Variables}]%

    }{}%
  }%
  \itemsep\nomitemsep% Restore spacing
} 


\begin{document}
This is my text document.
\nomenclature[a]{$\sigma$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$\alpha$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$\beta$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$A$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$B$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$C$}{Variable explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{$D$}{Variable explanation}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

Comment: how to add some spacing say 0.5\ \nomitemorigsep bewteen Other Variables and A? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to set a precise spacing, and would just like to set single spacing, you can wrap `\printnomenclature` in a single space environment:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{a}{Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{b}{Acronyms}{}}%
]}

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[a]{$x$}{Symbol explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$y$}{Symbol explanation}
\nomenclature[a]{$z$}{Symbol explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{A}{Acronym explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{B}{Acronym explanation}
\nomenclature[b]{C}{Acronym explanation}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature}
\begin{singlespace}
\printnomenclature
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

In this case the document will be double spaced (because of the `doublespacing` argument passed to the `setspace` package, and the nomenclature will be single spaced.

To compile this example, make sure to run `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls` for the nomenclature to print, where  is the name of the `.tex` file.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me. Are you using `report` class?

Comment: I realized my example code wasn't running, so I fixed it, and for me the single line spacing in the nomenclature still runs as expeced.